# Locating tempory files from raster processes in R: 140 Gb missing

Tags: r, random-forest, raster

I recently ran a script that was meant to stack multiple large rasters and run a randomforest classification on the stack.  I've done this numerous times with success, though it always takes up tremendous amounts of storage.

I'm aware of ways to check and clear the temporary folder in raster package:  `rasterTmpFile(prefix='r_tmp_')`, `showTmpFiles()`, `removeTmpFiles(h=24)`, `TmpDir()`.

Typically when the process is complete and I no longer need the temp files, I go to the folder and delete them.  Last night, the process ran, and `140 Gb` of storage space were consumed, but there is no temp data (in `raster - tmp folder`, or others).  Also these files were not written to `.tif`.

I do not understand what is happening.  Where is the data?  How can I remove it?